# Updating a column in two associated tables at once using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've been going round in circles with this. I'm learning a lot, except the one thing I'm trying to do.

I have two tables, Projects and Tickets, and I'm trying to ensure that when a Project's title is updated, the name of the project in all associated tickets will also update.

I'm new to sequelize and don't know extensively Postgres. I understand associations, foreign keys etc but a piece of the puzzle is missing. I cannot find a way to achieve what I want to do using Sequelise, it's time to ask for help.

My models are as follow (I've left out attributes not required for my question)

```
 const Project = db.define('project', {
    title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    description: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
});

const Ticket = db.define('ticket', {
    title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    project: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
});
```

How can update automatically the Ticket "project" column when the "title" column changes in the Project model?

Thank you so much in advance
Will

Answer (score 0):

In you **`x.model.js`**, you need put the following:

```
// In my case
Users.associate = function (models) {
  this.hasMany(
    models.get('projects', { as: 'projects', onUpdate: 'CASCADE' })
  );
  return this;
};
```

then in your other model:

```
// In my case
Projects.associate = function (models) {
  this.belongsTo(models.get('users'), {
    foreignKey: 'userId',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  });
  return this;
};
```

Finally you need sync you db:

```
db.sync();
```